# al enviar el formulario me abre el archivo .php que esta en el action="enviar.php"

Tags: php, html5, phpmailer

El problema es que tengo un formulario que quiero que se envíen los datos por medio de la función `mail` de `php` para que me caigan a mi correo personal
pero cuando le doy enviar al botón ya lleno el formulario lo que hace es abrirme el archivo `enviar.php` en el navegador no se por qué.

Tengo el siguiente código en `html`:

```
<form action="php/enviar.php"  method="post" class="mt-5" name="formulario"  id="formulario">
                    
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" 
       placeholder="Tu Nombre" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" 
       placeholder="Tu Email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" 
        name="telefono" placeholder="Tu Numero" required>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
                            
    <select  class="form-control" name="servicio" id="servicio" required>
                                     
          <option value="uno">1</option>
                                     
          <option value="dos">2</option>
                                     
          <option value="tres">3</option>
                                     
          <option value="cuatro">4</option>
    </select>

    </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" name="btn" 
       id="btn">Enviar</button>
```

y tengo este código en un archivo llamado `enviar.php` dentro de una carpeta `php`:

```
<?php 
$destino = "info@micorreo.com";
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$servicio = $_POST["servicio"];
$contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $correo . "\nTelefono: " . $telefono . "\nServicio: " . $servicio;
mail($destino,"Contacto", $contenido);
header("location:index.html");

?>
```

Lo que espero es que envíe los datos al correo proporcionado mediante la función de `mail` en `php` y no me abra el archivo `enviar.php` en el navegador.

Comment: Lo más probable es que no estás corriendo el proyecto en el directorio de publicación del servidor web, Apache (xampp, wamp), IIS, etc. El formulario se interpreta bien porque es html puro, pero el PHP necesita un webserver para poder ser ejecutado en el navegador.

Comment: `enviar.php` está dentro de la carpeta `php`, luego `index.html` debería estar dentro de la misma carpeta para que funcione esta redirección `header("location:index.html");`. Si no es el caso, debes cambiar la ruta de la redirección... algo como esto: `header("location: ../index.html");` _solo en caso de que esté en un nivel superior_

Comment: ¿Podrías revisar el log de error de tu servidor web? Indicas que el navegador abre el archivo PHP, imagino que para descargar. En ese caso por algún motivo tu servidor no está interpretando PHP. ¿Podrías indicar tu sistema operativo y el servidor web y versión de PHP que estás usando? También suele ser el comportamiento normal si lo que estás haciendo es abrir en el navegador el archivo HTML local y no a través del servidor web.

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo resolví fue de mucha ayuda sus comentarios gracias colegas.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar cómo lo arreglaste para que quede constancia de ello y pueda ayudar a otra persona con el mismo problema? Gracias.

Comment: hola @OscarGarcia  en realidad el codigo estaba bien el problema era que no lo estaba corriendo en un webserver como lo dijo el colega, lo subi al hosting y listo funciono de maravilla.

Answer (score -1):

La solucion esta en que tines que borrar el action he incluir el archivo php con el funcion include, pero antes tines que cambiar la extencion del archivo del formulario a .php

Comment: Tu respuesta no soluciona el problema, porque no era de código sino la forma de ejecutarlo.

Comment: El AP publicó un comentario en la pregunta sobre la lo que hizo para solucionar el problema lo cual no tiene que ver con lo que propones.